# How does glide cancel an image download request?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Given a scenario, if we fast scroll through a list, glide should cancels the 
image request for views which are too far from focus. How does glide does that ? I have searched a lot but couldn't find anything substantial.

Answer (score 3):

use 
// Scrolling starts.

```
Glide.with(this).pauseRequests();
```

...
// Scrolling stops.

```
Glide.with(this).resumeRequests();
```

for that

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `onScrollStateChanged` of your recyclerView so that when you scroll you can detect if views moves and apply actions like the following

```java
setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        switch (scrollState) {
            case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE: // The view is not scrolling.
            case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL: // The user is scrolling using touch, and their finger is still on the screen
                Glide.with(...).resumeRequests(); // resume glide requests 
                break;
            case SCROLL_STATE_FLING: // The user had previously been scrolling using touch and had performed a fling
                Glide.with(...).pauseRequests(); // pause glide requests
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes